How to fix Fading Text RStudio IDE
When I scroll down into the script it seems that the text starts to fade and a top layer of text stays until I cliced again.

My specs:
Processor: Intel i7 1.8GHz, 2304 Mhz
RAM: 8 GB
I tried changing the Apperance to default but the problem stays the same.

